# Android save video in gallery from its path

Tags: java, android, file, file-handling

I hope you all doing good. I have been trying to save video in my gallery. I have video path which is already saved in a hidden folder. I just want to save that video in my gallery. Here is the code I might making a mistake. If you can resolved it out I will be thankful to you.

```
            File newfile;
            AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(Uri.parse( path), "r");
            FileInputStream in = videoAsset.createInputStream();
            String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
            File dir = new File(root + "/" + "Pictures");
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            newfile = new File(dir, "status_"+System.currentTimeMillis()+".mp4");
            if (newfile.exists()) newfile.delete();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(newfile);
            // Copy the bits from instream to outstream
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
    
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
    
            in.close();
            out.close();
```

By this code I am having this **no content provider /storage/emulated/0/android/data/**  exception. As I have already added provider for image and permissions to write storage, but I don't know what provider are needed for video's or the problem is with the code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution, the mistake I was making that not getting the proper **FileInputStream** from the start.
Just replace this

```
 AssetFileDescriptor videoAsset = getContentResolver().openAssetFileDescriptor(Uri.parse( path), "r");
 FileInputStream in = videoAsset.createInputStream();
```

with this and your good to go :D

```
  FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File(path));
```